# sql regex_replace on specified columns from multiple tables

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, replace, posix

**How do I apply regex_replace to multiple columns from multiple tables?**

I have 2 tables, "email" & "languageEmail", which each hold columns "bodyText" & "bodyHtml"
I want to replace all found links in these 4 columns with the same link + a new param.

So far I have made a regex (POSIX) that seem to match all my url links.

```
((http(s)?:\/\/)|(www\.))[a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=&\/?]{2,256}(\b|\s)
```

I have made a sql query that finds the desired columns.

```
SELECT 
  "email"."bodyText",
  "email"."bodyHtml",
  "languageEmail"."bodyText",
  "languageEmail"."bodyHtml"
FROM 
  "db"."email",
  "db"."languageEmail";
```

I have read postgres own documentation but there is no examples of using the regex_replace in a sql query, I have looked in oracles documentation and they have a few examples of something sort of similar to what I want to achieve, but I cannot seem to connect the dots myself and get it right.

**Example of what i want to achieve:**

languageEmail.bodyHtml at id 75 has value:

```
<h1>hello world</h1> <a href="www.awsome.com/yes">click here</a>
```

languageEmail.bodyText at id 75 has value:

```
hello worldcplease visit www.awsome.com/yes
```

I want to add the param &page=1 to all links/urls

so after running the query with regex_replace, languageEmail.bodyHtml at id 75 should look like:

```
<h1>hello wordl</h1> <a href="www.awsome.com/yes&page=1">click here</a>
```

languageEmail.bodyText at id 75 should look like:

```
hello worldcplease visit www.awsome.com/yes&page=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you replace the second quotation mark and HTML close sign '">' with '&page=1">'?

You can use it in a CASE WHEN statement

For example:

```
CASE
  WHEN URL ~ '%((http(s)?:\/\/)|(www\.))[a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=&\/?]{2,256}(\b|\s)%'
   THEN
     REGEXP_REPLACE(URL, '(\">)', '&page=1">') END) AS URL_appended
```

For your plain text example I would try something like concatenating the URL (is it always at the end?) with the string you need at the end

So:

```
   SELECT
    CASE
    WHEN URL ~ '%((http(s)?:\/\/)|(www\.))[a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=&\/?]{2,256} 
      (\b|\s)%'
       THEN URL || '&page=1' END AS URL_appended
    FROM your_url_table)
```

I think that should be it :D

Comment: That would work in all the html bodys' yes, but in the plain text emails, there is no html closing tags, so it wont work there unfortunately.

Comment: This works in the context of your question though, can you update with the plain text example?

Comment: @RasmusPuls Updated my answer

Comment: Aha, so you would add a identifiable string and replace that with the desired param. In my perfect would, I would have thougth something like this would have worked: REGEX_REPLACE(select col from table, '(reg)?ex(\b)', '(reg)?ex(\b)&=page1').... That would have been joyfull. Will see if i can get your suggested solution to work! thanks

Comment: Actually I was being a bit unnecessary before. If we think about it, we don't need the replacement at all. Once you have the URL in it's own column, just concatenate with &page=1.

Comment: Once you now have the concatenated URL, you could then replace the original URL with the concatenated own using REGEXP_REPLACE

Comment: Right, now it looks a lot less redundant! ;)